# Checkbox sends same value, no matter if checked or not - javascript, html

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I have a checkbox on my site looking like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="jobfixedstart_cb" onclick="jobfixedstartfunc();" />
```

In a Javascript .onClick-Event I get the value of the checkbox like this:

```
var addjobfixedstart = document.forms["add-new-job"].jobfixedstart_cb.value;
```

Now, no matter if the checkbox is checked or not, the value of "addjobfixedstart" is always "on". If I give the checkbox a value, it always sends the value.

What am i doing wrong?

**Edit**:
I checked the status of the variable with an "alert" after the variable like that:

```
alert(addjobfixedstart);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following if you are trying to know whether a checkbox is checked or not

```
document.getElementById('jobfixedstart_cb').checked
```

This returns boolean. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, i came to the same result ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check checked status you should read `checked` property. For checkbox `value` read `value` property. In addition, listen to `onchange` event, rather then `onclick`.

All together it will become:

```js
function jobfixedstartfunc() {
 var checkbox = document.forms["add-new-job"].jobfixedstart_cb;
  alert('Checked:' + checkbox.checked + ', value:' + checkbox.value)
}
```

```html
<form name="add-new-job">
  <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="jobfixedstart_cb" onchange="jobfixedstartfunc();" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I tryed something different now which worked.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work by checking the checkbox like this:

```
var addjobfixedstart = document.getElementById("jobfixedstart_cb").checked
```

You get back a "true" of "false" value which you can work with.